# Where is the default parameter in Python function

Tags: python

I think many people have seen the python's function which receives default parameters. For example:

```
def foo(a=[]):
    a.append(3)
    return a
```

If we call this function using foo(), the output will append integer '3' each time after the call.

When this function is defined, a function object named 'foo' is defined in the current environment, and also the default parameter values are evaluated at this time. Every time when the function is called without a parameter, the evaluated parameter value will be changed according to the code.

My question is, **where is this evaluated parameter exist?** 
**Is it in the function object or it is in the method object when calling the function?**
Since everything in python is a object, there must be some place to hold the name->value binding of 'a'-->evaluated parameter. Am I over-thinking this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others already said, the default values are stored in the function object.

For example, in CPython you can do this:

```
>>> def f(a=[]):
...     pass
...
>>> f.func_defaults
([],)
>>> f.func_code.co_varnames
('a',)
>>>
```

However, `co_varnames` may contain more than names of args so it needs further processing and these attributes might not even be there in other Python implementations. Therefore you should use the `inspect` module instead which takes care of all implementation details for you:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> spec = inspect.getargspec(f)
>>> spec
ArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=([],))
>>>
```

The `ArgSpec` is a named tuple so you can access all values as attributes:

```
>>> spec.args
['a']
>>> spec.defaults
([],)
>>>
```

As the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) says, the `defaults` tuple always corresponds to the n last arguments from `args`. This gives you your mapping.

To create a dict you could do this:

```
>>> dict(zip(spec.args[-len(spec.defaults):], spec.defaults))
{'a': []}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's attached to the function object, see `foo.func_defaults`:

```
>>> foo()
>>> foo.func_defaults
([3],)
>>> foo()
>>> foo.func_defaults
([3, 3],)
```

In case if you want to get the mapping of `a` onto `[]`, you can access `foo.func_code`:

```
defaults = foo.func_defaults
# the args are locals in the beginning:
args = foo.func_code.co_varnames[:foo.func_code.co_argcount] 
def_args = args[-len(defaults):]  # the args with defaults are in the end
print dict(zip(def_args, defaults)) # {'a': []}
```

(But, apparently, the yak's version is better.)

Comment: Yes, but where is the mapping of `a` to the `[]` as the OP has asked?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the function object, in the `func_defaults`:

```
def f(a=[]): a.append(3)

print f.func_defaults # ([],)

f()

print f.func_defaults # ([3],)
```

Comment: Yes, but where is the mapping of a to the [] as the OP has asked?

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in the `func_defaults` attribute of the function object.

```
>>> foo.func_defaults
([],)
>>> foo()
([3],)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an interesting situation: in python 2.5.2 version, try the function 'foo()'

```
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1]
```

Because the objects of the function called are different:

```
>>> id(foo())
4336826757314657360
>>> id(foo())
4336826757314657008
>>> id(foo())
4336826757314683160
```

In 2.7.2 version:

```
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1, 1]
```

In this case, the object is the same each time calling the function:

```
>>> id(foo())
29250192
>>> id(foo())
29250192
>>> id(foo())
29250192
```

Is it a problem of different versions?

Comment: Shouldn't happen. Make sure you're using *exactly* the same functions on both versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `funcdefaults` is `__defaults__`:

```
>>> def foo(a=[]):
...     a.append(3)
...     return a
... 
>>> foo.__defaults__
([],)
```