# In python, how to store 'constants' for functions only once?

Tags: python, global-variables, constants

Some function need 'constant' values (i.e. not designed to be redefined later) that are not to be parametrized. While default arguments are [stored only once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121437/611007) for [each function](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112004749/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm), some are just not very meaningful to be put as parameters (i.e. to be part of the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_%28computer_science%29)). For (a not very useful) example:

```
def foo(bar):
    my_map = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
    return my_map.get(bar,defaultType)()
```

It wasted CPU time and RAM space to re-define such a constant for each call. Some other ways are to store such constants as module level globals or make the function a callable class, but there may be other ways, maybe?

When doing *the module level global* way, I prefix my (meant as a) constant variable with a "_" to show that it is there *not* for anyone's interest. Still I feel the module namespace slightly *"polluted"*, not to speak of the [shame of using](http://xkcdsw.com/1394) something [as discouraged as globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135345/) at all:

```
_my_map = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
def foo(bar):
    return _my_map.get(bar,defaultType)()
```

Or the *transform it into a class* way. I make the `__call__` a [classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/), to avoid the need of creating instances:

```
class foo:
   my_map = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
   @classmethod
   def __call__(cls,bar):
       return cls.my_map.get(bar,defaultType)()
```

Are these solutions pythonic enough?

Are there other ways to do this?

Is it even ok as a practice to use such 'constants'?

**Note** these objects in my examples are not necessarily actual *constants*, but used (and could be thought) as such by their purpose.

Comment: As is mentioned in one of those answers (and I agree with it), you would probably want to put a comment to make it extra specific that it is a global variable, also, you'd expect people reading your code to have a good understanding of Python. Though I admit I am curious to a more elegant solution as well!

Comment: Global constants are fine. It's global *state* that causes problems.

Comment: Why'd you link to xkcdsw instead of xkcd? o_0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set it as an [attribute on the function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232):

```
def foo(bar):
    return foo.my_map.get(bar, defaultType)()
foo.my_map = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
```

A callable class or a closure is not simple enough IMO.

Comment: Could you provide insight if this can be done inside a *class definition*? My attempts with either instance-, class- or staticmethods result in either `AttributeError` or `NameError`; it's also not obvious that if it's possible, can the function attribute kept 'close' to the function definition (in terms of lines in the file)?

Comment: Both of these work: https://gist.github.com/anossov/5411655 I'm not sure it's better than just class-level constants though.

Comment: my wrong, I didn't actually tested them with instance methods (I thought I did - when I try to do this with `@staticmethod` or `classmethod`, in some cases it gives *"AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute"* which tricked me.) So my real problem seems to be using the *@classmethod* and *@staticmethod* decorators with this. https://gist.github.com/naxa/5411709

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, there is nothing wrong with module level constants.

Note that according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), constants should be all upper case, like this:

```
_MY_MAP = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
def foo(bar):
    return _MY_MAP.get(bar,defaultType)()
```

The regular expression module in the standard library uses this style and many established third-party libraries do as well. If you are not convinced, just go to your `site-packages` directory and grep:

```
egrep "^_?[A-Z]+ =" *
```

Comment: If a module level global is meaningful for the outside, I also think that in Python it is useful. But a function helper like this is not very well structured like this because only its name shows where it belongs and its purpose.

Comment: I can see your point. I just wanted to point out that private module level constants are relatively common and probably not considered an anti-pattern in Python. It's a matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use closures:

```
def make_foo():
    my_map = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}
    def foo(bar):
        return my_map.get(bar,defaultType)()
    return foo
foo = make_foo()
```

Comment: I would also suggest renaming `make_foo()` to `foo()` -- although that may be a `foo` too many ;-).

Comment: I like this, and i'm starting to use it.  The only thing i have against it is that the args of the function are a bit hidden within the internal definition.  So callers need to look a little harder (especially if make_foo() is renamed to foo as martineau suggests).  Is there a way to make the parameters more visible to readers?

Answer (score 1):

To make something that is as self-contained as possible. You could create a [function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) (aka *functor*) class and give it a `__call__()` method *or* a `classmethod` (but probably not both):

```
class bazType(object): pass
class barType(object): pass
class fooType(object): pass

class Foo(object):
    _DEFAULT_TYPE = bazType
    _MY_MAP = {"rab": barType, "oof": fooType}

    def __call__(self, bar):
        return self._MY_MAP.get(bar, self._DEFAULT_TYPE)()

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, bar):
        return cls._MY_MAP.get(bar, cls._DEFAULT_TYPE)()

# using classmethod
print Foo.foo("rab")

# using __call__ method
foo = Foo()
print foo("baz")

# alternative way to use classmethod
foo = Foo.foo
print foo("oof")
```

Yet another alternative would be to define a `staticmethod`, which I won't illustrate because it's so similar to the other two -- but you get the idea I hope.