# python fails to call another function in args

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I recently worked on a simple and basic encryption program. (**skip reading the code before reading the question**)

```
def generator():
    enckey="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    a=list(enckey)
    random.shuffle(a)
    c=''
    for i in a:
        c+=i
    c=c+a[0]
    return c


def senc(a,enckey=generator()):
    b=list(a)
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        for j in range(0,27):
            if b[i]==enckey[j]:
                b[i]=enckey[j+1]
                break
    c=''
    for i in b:
        c+=i
    print("Encrypted text:",c,"\nEncryption Key:",enckey)
```

Now when I call the function `senc("argument")`, it generates a `enckey` and uses it to encrypt the supplied text. Now, since I say that `enckey=generator()` I expect that every time `senc` is executed it will re execute generator to get a key. But this did not happen.

The following is the proof:

```
>>> id(senc("Andy"))
Encrypted text: Arnj 
Encryption Key: htpkzwqlxcsdnregobvaimyjufh
1655676136
>>> id(senc("Candy"))
Encrypted text: Cirnj 
Encryption Key: htpkzwqlxcsdnregobvaimyjufh
1655676136
```

Both are at the same memory address and as seen the encryption key is same. Where did I go wrong, and why does it not call the function?

Please note that the encryption key does change for every new instance of IDLE/commandprompt, etc.

Comment: The default value is evaluated when the function is defined, not when the function is called.

Comment: See [Common Gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated only once, when the function gets defined. If you want to have a new generator each time you invoke the function without `enckey` parameter, you should do:

```
def senc(a,enckey=None):
    if enckey is None:
        enckey = generator()
    b=list(a)
    ...
```

Comment: this implies that it remembers the default value, can I get it's memory address/clear it from there?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120974/where-is-the-default-parameter-in-python-function

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It also seems to be writable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784840/are-you-allowed-to-modify-func-defaults-defaults-in-python-3-x-in-python. But that would be an ugly and difficult to understand way to do this, while using `None` as a default is the commonly understood, traditional way to do it.